# Load an xml file more than 0kb

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse xml files there are many files and some are 0kb.
When a file of 0kb is found it is throwing an exception root element is missing and ends. I have tried a try catch block but it does not continue after the error and the program stops.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Simply Load File and check File length.if greater then zero do your processing

Comment: Show your current codes when you ask question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the FileInfo class to check the file size, and only if the length is greater than zero try and parse the XML, like so:

```
var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName); //where fileName is the full path to the XML file

if (fileInfo.Length > 0)
{
    //read the xml
}
```